# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in js using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 function makePvsApplicantCalls(){
         console.log('In makePvsApplicantCalls'); 
         $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: "/reppify/RPCPostAdapter/httprpc/applicationFacade/getPreviousApplicants",
             data : {jobId : jobId, page: pgNoPA++},
             cache: false,
             beforeSend: function(){
                 console.log('In makePvsApplicantCalls Before Send'); 
             },                     
             success: onSuccessPA,
             complete: function(){  
                 $('#prevSpinner').hide();
             },
             error: handleError,
             dataType: 'json'
        });
}
```

On Calling above javascript function, I'm getting following exception on browser and not able to make AJAX call, following is the invoking code

```
if(data.result>0) {
    makePvsApplicantCalls();
}
```

Following is the error

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery.min.js:4
    e jquery.min.js:4
    ca jquery.min.js:2
    ca jquery.min.js:2
    ca jquery.min.js:2
    ca jquery.min.js:2
    f.extend.param jquery.min.js:4
    f.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
    makePvsApplicantCalls b2bscreening.js:2584
    $.ajax.success b2bscreening.js:2451
    n jquery.min.js:2
    o.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
    w jquery.min.js:4
    d jquery.min.js:4
```

How can I get rid of this exception?

Comment: Where and how are you invoking it?

Comment: onSuccessPA is another function, which is available in my JS file and even beforeSend is not working

Comment: For debugging, always use non-minified versions of jQuery. Then show us the stacktrace, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got my mistake, actually I was feeding two data input and unfortunately only 1 was global variable and one was local, **RESOLVED NOW**.

Comment: Interesting....I know I shouldn't be posting "Thanks, me too!"s, but this was causing the same problem for me which I've been trying to debug for hours. Interesting how you can't pass both local and global variabes... I wonder why that is.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Try wrapping your success and error properties into functions because functions are expected there</del>

Are you sure you are sending the data properly?

```
data : {'jobId' : jobId, 'page': pgNoPA++}
```

Comment: No that's not a problem, I'm already making 100 of such calls but Im stuck in this only

Comment: That does not make a difference, `onSuccessPA` and `handleError` **are** functions. All you do is adding one level of indirection...

Comment: And 'jobId' don't need to be in quotes, just jobId, page is sufficient.