# Uncaught TypeError Illegal invocation when send FormData along with file to ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi When i Tried to submit a form along with form data i am getting " Illegal invocation" in the browser console here is the code

```
 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('rut', formDataSerialized.rut); // add the file details
 formData.append('firstName', formDataSerialized.firstName); // add the file details
 formData.append('lastName', formDataSerialized.lastName); // add the file details
 formData.append('email', formDataSerialized.email); // add the file details
 formData.append('phone', formDataSerialized.phone); // add the file details
 formData.append('files', ($('input[type=file]').length-1)); // add the file details*/
 for(var i = 0; i< ($('input[type=file]').length-1); i++) {
     var options = $('input[type=file]')[i].files[0].value;
     options = JSON.stringify(options);
     formData.append("attach"+i,  options);
 }

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false, // Don't process the files
    contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
    success: function(data){
        if(typeof data.error === 'undefined'){
            nc.adapters.loaderFormAdapter.hide(self);
            if (data.portletData.errors) {
                  self.validator.showFormErrorMessage(self.content.find('.form'), data.portletData.errors !== undefined? data.portletData.errors: data.portletData.exceptionMessage);
                //self.disableSubmitButton();
                return;
            } else {
                self.renderTemplate(
                    self.content,
                    '',
                    {}
                ).done(function() {
                    $(self.content.find('.jsTryAgain')).on('click', self.onTryAgain.bind(self));                                    
                });
                return;
            }   
            self.renderTemplate(self.content, '', {});
        }else{
            displayServiceUnAvailablePopup.call(this);
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        displayServiceUnAvailablePopup.call(this);
    }
});
```

Firstly i have tried so many links before posting this question none of them have worked. here are some of the links

[Uncaught TypeError Illegal invocation when send FormData to ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258161/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-when-send-formdata-to-ajax)

[JQuery: 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation' at ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531213/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-at-ajax-request)

[Jquery and HTML FormData returns "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755945/jquery-and-html-formdata-returns-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation)

[$.post throwing "Illegal invocation "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729442/post-throwing-illegal-invocation)

[Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in js using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525586/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-js-using-jquery)

[jQuery - Illegal invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324594/jquery-illegal-invocation)

Comment: Is there a specific line that error happens on? In the console you might see the exact line that is causing the issue, if so, what is it? Also, did you try taking each `append` statement out 1-by-1 to see if it starts working at some point, possibly isolating the appended data causing the issue?

Comment: Probably start debugging by just passing a simple `formData` variable to the ajax call, eg: `var formData = new FormData();  formData.append('test', 'test');` and use that in the ajax call.  If that doesn't throw an error then you know the problem is in the formdata variable.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind tried by removing the files once and tried by removing all the data. it is giving the same error

Comment: @FrançoisWahl the error is coming at the below location

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind got the issues at this point  value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );

Comment: Yeah only other things to check is your success function, take out the success function and try it.  Also make sure your `url` variable is set.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Tried Removing success and checked URL variable. URL variable is set and the issue is coming after removing success function as well

Comment: Most likely the problem is in the `formData`, in my opinion.  Check that out some more.  Also double check your ijquery version and make sure the error isn't coming from another place.  good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just change contentType from 'json' to 'text'.